# Simulate disk out of space exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows, out-of-memory

In our application we want to check the disk out of space exception. What is the best way to simulate this situation without using a bulk amount of chunk files.

Comment: without any detals about your application this is hard to tell - you could for example use a VM with "small HDDs" configured or you could just mock the object accessing the disk and throw an out of space exception and see what happens...

Comment: @Yahia: can i just create a large file using fsutil file createnew command. whether it will cause any other issues?

Comment: you can BUT since the disk is used by the whole OS (other programs etc.) you could make the whole machine unstable (depending the other SW running)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many methods (virtual drives, small partitions, even a huge file to fill your test partition).

Usually I prefer to use a **disk quota** because it's fast to change (so I test by hand in few seconds but I can also integrate it in my automated tests) and I'm free to try different conditions (low disk space, very low disk space, disk full). Moreover You can also handle "out of disk quota" and "disk full" differently (if required).

Assign a disk quota for a specific user and run the application with that credentials. If quota is small enough you can simulate a disk out of space (and you can check with various values without creating tons of files).

It can be done [through UI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728132%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or simply via [command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755913%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) with `fsutil`:

```
fsutil quota modify k: 1000000
```

Comment: can i just create a large file using fsutil file createnew command. whether it will cause any other issues?

Comment: Yes, of course you can (as you can use a virtual machine) but it may take a long time if your hard disk is big, it depends on what you feel more comfortable with. Usually I prefer quota 'cause I can check few different conditions without changes to partitions and I can simulate what I want in few seconds (stress tests are boring, we know).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows 7 or Windows 2008 R2 you can create a [small virtual disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872416.aspx), mount it and test your application there. This way, the "low disk space" disk is isolated from the O.S. disks and other applications.

To do this, open up Disk Management, and select Create VHD. Choose a suitably small size, create the disk, initialize it, and them map it.

Alternatively, you can create and mount the virtual disk using the `DiskPart` command line utility.

The VHD itself is just a file on your main disk; this means you could ship the VHD with any tests suites, and mount it before you run your tests. This gives you an advantage over more "system" based approaches such as changing the disk quota, because it can be automated into your tests with minimal effort.

Answer (score 2):

```
throw new System.IO.IOException("There is not enough space on the disk.");
```